# Angular - 1 page on Web, 2 Pages on mobile

Tags: angular

I have the following situation:

- I have a form and a resulting list of items
- On the mobile screen the user should be able to submit the form on one page, and be redirected to the next page for the results
- On a desktop the form and result should appear on the same page

How do you handle such a situation using angular?

Do I only create one page and hide/show the form/list on the mobile using media queries and reacting to the "submit"?

What is the best practice here?

Comment: Have you considered use CSS media queries, landscape (for web/tablet) and portrait (for mobile)?

Comment: Try *ngIf else in angular 4. Hide the form on submit and show the result page